# Use custom property attribute to map value to another type

Tags: c#, reflection, mapping, custom-attributes

I"m trying to put together an abstract class that various models in my MVVM will derive from.  Part of this is for abstracting IEditableObject/IChangeTracking details.

For my IEditableObject, I want to store a shallow copy of "core data" (a struct that defines data that will be serialized, typically for database storage) so that it can be cancelled or committed.  What I don't want to do is type this out for each new Model that I come up with.

I've defined a [DataCoreItem] custom attribute that I thought to use on the derived class's applicable properties.  For some unrelated reasons, the abstract class takes a generic DataCoreType and IDType:

```
    public abstract class ModelObject<T, DataCoreType, IDType> : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{

    public abstract DataCoreType Load(IDType id);
    public abstract bool Save(DataCoreType dataCore);
    public abstract bool Delete(IDType id);
    // etc...
```

Here's an example for my CompanyModel
the data core:

```
public struct CompanyDataCore
{
    public int? ID;
    public string Code;
    public string Name;
    public string PrimaryWebsite;
    public string PrimaryPhone;
    public string PrimaryEmail;
}
```

the derived class:

```
public class CompanyModel : ModelObject<CompanyModel, CompanyDataCore, int> {

    CompanyDataCore dataCore;

    [DataCoreMember]
    public int? ID { get { return dataCore.ID; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.ID, value); } }
    [DataCoreMember]
    public string Name { get { return dataCore.Name; } set {SetProperty(ref dataCore.Name, value); } }
    [DataCoreMember]
    public string Code { get { return dataCore.Code; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.Code, value); } }
    [DataCoreMember]
    public string PrimaryPhone { get { return dataCore.PrimaryPhone; } set {SetProperty(ref dataCore.PrimaryPhone, value); } }
    [DataCoreMember] 
    public string PrimaryEmail { get { return dataCore.PrimaryEmail; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.PrimaryEmail, value); } }
    [DataCoreMember]
    public string PrimaryWebsite { get { return dataCore.PrimaryWebsite; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.PrimaryWebsite, value); } }
```

Ok, finally... what I'd like for my abstract class is to use the BeginEdit(), EndEdit() and CancelEdit() methods to handle storage of a backup copy of the data core automatically.  Here's how I envision it:

```
[DataCoreMember(MemberName="ID")]
public int? ID { get { return dataCore.ID; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.ID, value); } }
// etc etc
```

and in my abstract class:

```
    public virtual void BeginEdit() {

        Type t = typeof(T);

        var props = t.GetProperties().Where(
            prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(DataCoreMemberAttribute)));


        // WHAT TO DO HERE???  everything else looks good up to here
        foreach (object o in props) {
            this.dataCoreBackup.???? = o.value;
        }

        IsEditing = true;
    }
```

How to map the property to which the DataCoreMember is applied to the property of the struct as specified?

I'm inexperienced with reflection (and working generic types as well for that matter), but I gather that this can be done.  I've found examples (as of yet untried) for how to get a list of those properties with the attribute applied to them, but I'm unsure how to ultimately reference the DataCore's property based on that.  Can anyone show me how?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Followup question: as I understand, these attributes are handled at runtime with no real developer control over their time of availability.  Am I taking the wrong approach in attempting to use this meta information to provide functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a fairly easy task with Reflection.  Explanation below (with much of the non-pertinent code stripped out)

This holds the data backup so CancelEdit is supported:

```
public struct CompanyDataCore
{
    public int? ID;
    public string Code;
    public string Name;
    public string PrimaryWebsite;
    public string PrimaryPhone;
    public string PrimaryEmail;
    public string RootPath;
}
```

Here's the attribute class to denote which fields get backed up:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class DataCoreMemberAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the derived class:

```
public class CompanyModel : ModelObject<CompanyModel, CompanyDataCore, int>
{

    [Identifier]
    [DataCoreMember(MemberName="ID")]
    public int? ID { get { return dataCore.ID; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.ID, value); } }

    [DataCoreMember(MemberName="Name")]
    public string Name { get { return dataCore.Name; } set {SetProperty(ref dataCore.Name, value); } }

    [DataCoreMember(MemberName="Code")]
    public string Code { get { return dataCore.Code; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.Code, value); } }

    [DataCoreMember(MemberName="PrimaryPhone")]
    public string PrimaryPhone { get { return dataCore.PrimaryPhone; } set {SetProperty(ref dataCore.PrimaryPhone, value); } }

    [DataCoreMember(MemberName="PrimaryEmail")] 
    public string PrimaryEmail { get { return dataCore.PrimaryEmail; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.PrimaryEmail, value); } }

    [DataCoreMember(MemberName="PrimaryWebsite")]
    public string PrimaryWebsite { get { return dataCore.PrimaryWebsite; } set { SetProperty(ref dataCore.PrimaryWebsite, value); } }

}
```

And here's the abstract class:

```
public abstract class ModelObject<T, DataCoreType, IDType> : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    protected DataCoreType dataCoreBackup;

    public virtual void BeginEdit() {

        Type t = typeof(T);

        // get a the properties with the attribute
        var props = t.GetProperties().Where(
            prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(DataCoreMemberAttribute)));

        // backup needs to be boxed because it's a struct
        object boxedBackup = this.dataCoreBackup;

        foreach (var prop in props) {

            foreach (CustomAttributeData attribData in prop.GetCustomAttributesData()) {

                if (attribData.Constructor.DeclaringType == typeof(DataCoreMemberAttribute)) {

                    object origValue = prop.GetValue(this);
                    FieldInfo field = boxedBackup.GetType().GetField(attribData.NamedArguments[0].TypedValue.Value.ToString());
                    field.SetValue(boxedBackup, origValue);
                }
            }
        }

        this.dataCoreBackup = (DataCoreType)boxedBackup;

        IsEditing = true;
    }
```

... and now I can get INotifiyPropertyChanged and IEditbaleObject handled in an abstract class so I don't have to write a bunch of plumbing in each specific model that I'm going to use.

Hopefully someone else can find this useful.